# Select from table and view, with left join and where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table (GamesSchedule) which includes tournament name, referee name, dates, and then a view with a list of all tournaments. What I need is the number of games in each tournament for a specific referee during a specific date range – and I do need the nulls to see if there's a tournament that the referee hasn't worked in (and, no, I haven't found an answer that helps me properly):

```
  Tourney  | Games
----------------
Mens 1st   | 10
Womens 1st |  7
Cup        |  0
Youth      |  3
Mens 2nd   |  2
Womens 2nd |  0
----------------
```

This, unfortunately, gives me only the tournaments where the referee has worked games (so only four lines out of six, no cup games as above):

```
    SELECT t.Tourney, COUNT(t.Tourney) AS Games
      FROM GamesSchedule t
RIGHT JOIN Tournaments v
        ON t.Tourney = v.Tourney
     WHERE Date > 42603 AND Date < 43011 
       AND (D1='Joe Smith' OR D2='Joe Smith' OR D3='Joe Smith')
     GROUP BY t.Tourney;
```

Comment: You should provide more information, like the structure of the GamesSchedule table (at least the fields relevant for this query)  and what columns you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving condition from `WHERE` to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.Tourney, COUNT(t.Tourney) AS Games 
FROM GamesSchedule t 
RIGHT JOIN Tournaments v 
  ON t.Tourney = v.Tourney 
AND Date > 42603 
AND Date < 43011 
AND 'Joe Smith' IN (D1, D2, D3) 
GROUP BY t.Tourney;
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. I do get one more line in the results, but it doesn't contain the name of the tournament (only the number of games, which is 0), and there should be a lot more. The total number of tournaments is actually over 20.  Thanks for your advice, but I'm not there just yet.

Comment: @GFS Please preapre http://rextester.com demo and I am sure I could adjust this query to  your requirements.